# Hide nested git repo to outer repo

Tags: git, git-submodules, gitignore, git-subrepo

I have two clojure projects, A and B. Both of them are git repos. Project B is used as a packaged dependency in project A (a .jar).

To test and work on project B I need to use it in project A. So I clone B's repo inside A's root folder, and change the resolution path from the package (.jar) path to the new code path. When I'm finished, I move to B and from there I commit and push. So commits are made to B, and A is left intact.

The reason I don't use submodules is that I don't need A keeping any track of changes in B. The only reason B is nested in A, is for my resolution engine (shadow-cljs) to find it. The same way that the packaged dependency is inside A's root. I understand that is the most common thing to have dependencies inside projects, unless they are global.

To avoid A's repo considering B a submodule I added B to `.gitignore` before I cloned it. However, git seems to create a submodule commit. I removed it with `git rm --cached` and committed, but as soon as I change branches, make changes or do some git stuff, it creates it so I have to remove it again.

I am using vscode, which recognizes both repos in the git panel, but doesn't show in any way that B is a submodule of A. Anyway, I have disabled the `git.detectSubmodules` config.

I`ve seen the update in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33835633) but it doesn't go into much detail. Also, it could be a problem with vscode, but I couldn't find anything about that.

Comment: Welcome to SO. So to clarify: you want to make commits on repo B (which is checked out to a subfolder of the folder of checked out repo A) without A adding any commits? In `git gui`, I am shown an additional file with the name of the submodule, which I have the option to submit or not. While you may have added `B/` (the folder) to `.gitignore`, you may also need to add `B` (the file) (or vice-versa).

Comment: @LokiRagnarok I had added `B`, but not `B/`. However, `git status` shows the name of the submodule itself, and the phrase _(new commits)_ as the description of the changes.